# Algorithm for review icon highlighting

Tags: support, review, top-bar

New top bar (for all Stack Overflow sites) contains a review icon:

> [image: review-icon]

In which situations the review icon is highlighted?

Related question on ruSO.Meta: [Подсветка иконки очереди проверок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5355/176217)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653) when this rolled out on Stack Overflow, we highlight the indicator *if*...

- You haven't clicked the review button on the top bar, reviewed any posts, or visited /review in some period of time (currently 60 minutes) *and*...
- ...There are more than a trivial number of tasks waiting to be reviewed (I set this manually to roughly half the median number of tasks normally pending in a given hour - this is subject to change at any time, as the number on which it is based has been all over the map as we've been making changes to the top bar and review criteria these past few months. The default is 3, but it's currently set to 513 on SO and 30 on RUSO).

Comment: Thanks for answer here. I've already found your answer on MSO and made translation to Russian on related ruSO question.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that - but the thresholds are different over there, so I wanted an answer that'd apply to all sites with the new top bar.

Comment: On https://buddhism.stackexchange.com (with the new topbar) I see the icon frequently lit, but when I click on it all the queues are empty. Is this a bug? A known feature? Is it trying to train me to ignore the icon's being lit?

Comment: It's set to light up when there are at least 3 items awaiting review, @ChrisW; that's not very hard to get across all queues, especially when waiting for someone else to come along. Do me a favor, will you? I just switched it to the experimental "danger zone" logic, which is triggered by per-queue thresholds; let me know if that seems more accurate.

Comment: Previously it was lighting up frequently, but when I clicked on it it said there were 0 items for me in every queue -- so it was frequently false positive. Now it seems to be lighting up never (I haven't seen it lit up once since you posted your comment 2 days ago); when I click on it just now it shows 2 Late Answers, 1 First Post, and 1 Suggested Edit -- so, four items total, maybe a false negative. What I'd expect (and perhaps the only way for it to be really useful to me) would be for it to light up when and only when there's at least one thing in one queue for me to review.

Comment: Interesting. I will probably want to tweak this for small sites; it isn't lighting up on the assumption that more than 1 person is likely to see it (and thus try to review the same item simultaneously). That may not be an issue on Buddhism.