# Where should I ask questions related to all Stack Overflow sites (English and localized)?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

One of my recent question [Top bar stickiness doesn't work on mobile devices (iOS, Android) when focus is on the search bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296701/339911) was closed as off-topic. That question pertains to all Stack Overflow family sites: [English](http://stackoverflow.com), [Russian](http://ru.stackoverflow.com), [Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com), [Spanish](http://es.stackoverflow.com), [Japanese](http://ja.stackoverflow.com). Not only one specific as said in the closing reason:

> This question **pertains only to a specific site** in the Stack Exchange Network.

As far as I know new top bar duscussed in mentioned above question will be part of all Stack Exchange sites soon.

So where and why should I ask questions like mine recently closed?

Worth noting that [many of my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A339911%20%5Blocalization%5D) about [localization](/questions/tagged/localization) considered on-topic here on MSE. Most of these questions pertain only to Stack Overflow family.

Comment: [English Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: [One potential reason to ask these on MSO.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296736/algorithm-for-review-icon-highlighting#comment962887_296736)

Answer (score 3):

I would ask such questions on Meta Stack Overflow if English is doable for you. That site is monitored closely by community managers, so they will pick it up quite fast. If you are not proficient on English, I would ask it on the per-site-meta that suits you best.

There is no need to post it here on MSE since it hasn't been announced that the top bar will come across the network any time soon.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, I slightly updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

You're free to report bugs either on the per site meta or on Meta Stack Exchange. All meta's are patrolled for bug reports and there is no difference in the speedy delivery of fixes.

For site specific features, like Documentation or the Stack Overflow app, Meta Stack Overflow is the preferred place.

Until recently the new top bar design was only used on Stack Overflow proper so the reports about that feature were best asked there. Now that the feature gets rolled out to more sites, MSE becomes also appropriate to report overarching bugs on.

When top bar bugs are reported on MSE they shouldn't be closed any longer as *pertains only to a specific site*. Allow 6 to 8 weeks for the MSE close vote gang to adjust.